# I added a second harddrive and now I am trying to format the first one and I am having an issue

Tags: 13.04, disk, format

I just added a second faster hard-drive and it is working great! However I am having an issue formatting the original hard-drive (I already have everything backed up).

After going to the disk app and selecting the correct hard-drive i click on format. After about 10 seconds or so I receive this error

"Error formatting disk. Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Any ideas on how to either fix this issue or simply format my older hard-drive?

Comment: I know that if I goto "disk usage analyzer" I can select the correct hard-drive and move files to trash, but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. IF you have any comments regarding "disk usage analyzer" please also include them.

Comment: The information is in relation to clicking the "more actions" cog in the upper right corner of the "disk" window. When i select the "more actions" cog in the center of the window i receive a different error. "Error formatting volume... Error creating file system: Command-line `mkfs.ext4 -F -L "Storage Drive" "/dev/sdb1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sdb1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with GParted.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open it through the menu or typing `sudo gparted` in terminal.

Choose the disc you want to format, unmount it, select the partition type and apply the changes.

A guide with screenshots: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-format-a-sd-card-or-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: Thank you that was quite easy!!! Additionally I am once again using "disk" to delete partitions and overwrite all data just a quick question, how should this device be re written? Ext4, FAT, NTFS, or some other that I am unaware of.   This drive will most likely only be used in my Ubuntu computer, however I may try MINT or something else. What should I pick?

Comment: Well, if you are going to use that disk exclusively in UNIX-like systems, I would use ext4, but it's my opinion. If you think you are going to use that disk in other OS you might want to format in NTFS (FAT32 is limited to a 4GB file size).

Comment: With gparted i got following error "nput/output error during write on /dev/sdc"

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to download GParted Partition Editor a powerful partitioning programme. This can be downloaded through the Software Centre.

Comment: previously answered thank you though

Comment: not a problem. glad to help.